# How to map a column of xml data type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, nhibernate-mapping

I need to map a column of xml data type.
I think something like this might work but what type should i specify in type atribute? What is the coresponding C# data type to the postgres xml data type? (i need to write the mapping but the entities are not ready yet and might not be written by me)

```
    <property name="XmlFoo" type="">
        <column name="XmlFoo" sql-type="xml" />
    </property>
```

What is the proper way to do the mapping?

Thanks for replies!

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the right type is **StringClob** which is a specific **NHibernate Type**.
Using StringClob instead of just String allows it to have a **size over 4k**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<property name="XmlFoo" type="StringClob">
    <column name="XmlFoo" sql-type="xml" />
</property>
```

Comment: StringClob doesn't seem to be a known C# class

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `StringClob`?

The accepted answer (`type="StringBlob"`) didn't work for me, and I see no reference to `StringBlob` on [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes).

However, `type="StringClob"` worked like a charm (albeit on SQL Server.)

Comment: note sure if the API changed or me and Steve made a mistake (his initial answer was StringClob), but it seems this is the current correct usage